# How to create a user using WMIC interface

Tags: user-accounts, wmic

I am creating a user using command

```
USERACCOUNT CREATE NAME="test"
```

OUTPUT:

```
Create instance of 'Win32_UserAccount' class (Y/N)?y
ERROR:
Description = Unsupported parameter
```

This is the only format available on internet. Please suggest.

Comment: _"This is the only format available on internet"_ - where exactly did you find it?

Comment: I found it on following links
http://www.it-word.net/command/Windows/wmic/en-us/wmicUSERACCOUNT.html
https://www.windows-commandline.com/wmic-useraccounts/
There is no example given in microsoft docs to create users using this command
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc779647(v=ws.10)

Comment: I think this command doesn't exist. Your 1st link gives the 2nd one as a source. The 2nd one is a question by a commenter how to create a user. The command is an example how they imagine it should look. The response says this command doesn't exist and `net user` should be used instead.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That's why I posted question here to confirm that can I create a user with wmic or not? So you are agreeing the answer that we can't?